# App Center & taxes

Tags: appcenter

I want to release an app on the app center with payments. Do I have to calculate and pay the taxes by myself or is this already handled by elementary? I couln't find any information about it from elementary or stripe.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to calculate and pay the taxes by yourself in any country that has a revenue agency/taxation authority. Fiscal legislation also differs from one country to another. It also depends on how you are registered as a tax payer (business or individual). So you should address this question to your taxation authority help desk/help line, or an accountant from your country of residence.